# How to avoid 403 response when scraping goodreads?

Tags: express, asynchronous, xpath, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using cheerio to **scrape** goodreads.com (example page: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2). The code is below. The code initially works and I get the desired response from the server. However, after two successful attempts, the http response from goodreads returns with 403 (Forbidden). The forbidden response goes away after a few minutes. Is there a way to fix this behavior? Rate limit multiple request?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

var xpath = require('xpath'),
  dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

module.exports = {
  async searchBooks(req, res, next) {
    const booksArray = [];
    const { searchTerm, searchField } = req.body;
    axios
      .get('https://www.goodreads.com/search/index.xml', {
        params: {
          q: searchTerm,
          page: null,
          key: process.env.GOODREADS_KEY,
          'search[field]': searchField
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        const xml = result.data;
        var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
        const idsArr = xpath.select('//best_book/id', doc);
        const titlesArr = xpath.select('//title', doc);
        const namesArr = xpath.select('//name', doc);
        for (let i = 0; i < idsArr.length; i++) {
          const bookObject = {
            id: idsArr[i].firstChild.data,
            title: titlesArr[i].firstChild.data,
            author: namesArr[i].firstChild.data
          };
          booksArray.push(bookObject);
        }
        const urls = idsArr.map((id, index) => {
          return `https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/${id.firstChild.data}`;
        });
        return urls;
      })
      .then(async urls => {
        const promiseArray = urls.map(url => axios.get(url));
        const results = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
        const imgUrls = results.map((result, index) => {
          const $ = cheerio.load(result.data);
          const imgUrl = $('#coverImage').attr('src');
          return imgUrl;
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i++) {
          booksArray[i].image = imgUrls[i];
        }
        return res.json(booksArray);
      });
  }
};
```

EXPECTED:

```
[
  {
    "id": "49628",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "David Mitchell",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1406383769l/49628.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "6795",
    "title": "The Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Liam Callanan",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388200445l/6795.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "6797",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Donald Platt",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1165604675l/6797.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "9113096",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas (Novel)",
    "author": "Frederic P.  Miller",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1348108862l/9113096.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "42964582",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Lana Wachowski, Lilly Wachowski",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1543315136l/42964582.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "36514377",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Aileen Brennigan",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1509527373l/36514377.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "6270907",
    "title": "International Cloud Atlas, Vol. 2",
    "author": "G.O.P. Obasi",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1408629611l/6270907.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "17981504",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas (Web Toon/Manwa)",
    "author": "SIU",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1369643486l/17981504.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "20336925",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas: A BookCaps Study Guide",
    "author": "BookCaps",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1388272670l/20336925.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "16453357",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas (Novel)",
    "author": "Jesse Russell",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1356198781l/16453357.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "24416536",
    "title": "Anarchici - Matrix, Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Flavia Monceri",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1420884508l/24416536.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "254004",
    "title": "The Cloud Atlas Of China",
    "author": "National Meteorological Service of China"
  },
  {
    "id": "36368685",
    "title": "Weather: An Illustrated History: From Cloud Atlases to Climate Change",
    "author": "Andrew Revkin",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1530073964l/36368685.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "28288713",
    "title": "Histopias: From the Bible to Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Dragos Moraru"
  },
  {
    "id": "1522255",
    "title": "International Cloud Atlas: Volume I--Manual on the Observations of Clouds and Other Meteors",
    "author": "World Meteorological Organization"
  },
  {
    "id": "18949690",
    "title": "Atlas Cloud and the Witch of the West (Atlas Cloud Saga)",
    "author": "L.M.J. Rayner",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1385411062l/18949690.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "21898982",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas by David Mitchell l Summary & Study Guide",
    "author": "BookRags",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1397316499l/21898982.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "3338750",
    "title": "Cloud Atlas I, II, III: For Piano",
    "author": "Toshi Ichiyanagi"
  },
  {
    "id": "34169332",
    "title": "Postmodernism and Time in David Mitchell's Ghostwritten and Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Hoo-Ting Miranda Li"
  },
  {
    "id": "19675573",
    "title": "Postmodernist Intertextuality in David Mitchell's Cloud Atlas",
    "author": "Martina Hrubes",
    "image": "https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1387742749l/19675573.jpg"
  }
]
```

ACTUAL:

POST /api/goodreads/search - - ms - -
(node:63327) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the same limit as for their API:

> Not request any method more than once a second. Goodreads tracks all
> requests made by developers. [ref](https://www.goodreads.com/api/terms)

You may want to use the [Goodreads API](https://www.goodreads.com/api) instead of **scraping** the data.

This [tutorial](https://computerscience.fyi/which-book-should-i-read-next-recommendation-engine-with-item-item-collaborative-filtering/) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested links. I took your advice and scaled back the frequency of request to no more than 1 per second (1 per 5 seconds actually), which made with some success. However, after 19 successful queries, the temporary 403 forbidden response from goodreads is again triggered. I will take you advice and search for a more suitable API (the cover images offered by the goodreads API aren't of sufficient quality and are often entirely missing at times).